# Facebook implementation in android

Tags: android

i am trying to implement facebook in android.
I am following this tutorials.

[tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)

i got stuck at one point,[image]

i hv to execute this

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

but running it on cmd prompt is not working for me.

This tool generates a string that must be registered in the Mobile & Devices section of the Developer App for app. 
BUt i am not able to generate it.

plz,guide me to generate this.

Appreciate it

Comment: Your description "not working for me" is not working for me. Could you paste what happens?

Comment: He is trying to execute a Linux command on a Windows cmd.

Comment: can i run, this command on cmd promt?? for now, its giving me "| openssl sha1 -binary | was unexpected at this time"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both "keytool" and "openssl" installed on your system? "keytool" is part of the Java runtime environment (so it should be there as you're developing an Android app) and "openssl" is a standard package that should be easy to retrieve for your Mac (if it's not already installed). Both have to be executed on the command line. If both are indeed installed, what's the exact output from the above command?

Comment: i am using mac to develop android app.what i hv to do if i dont hv keytool and openssl, Nyarly???

Comment: or even if i use windows, than how can i get it?

Comment: First, check whether the tools are installed by executing them on the command line. Then, install the Java Development Environment (JDK) and the openssl package for Mac, depending on which is missing.

Comment: For Windows:
JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
OpenSSL: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

Comment: keytool is part of the JDK, just put $JAVA_HOME/bin in your classpath and you will be able to execute it. About openssl, I don't know for Mac but for windows the easiest way should be to download and install cygwin with the openssl package (check the openssl package during the installation process). Then under cygwin, you will be able to use the command

Comment: ok..i already hv jdk on my machine,i am downloading openSSL, for windows, and will try it there....thanks mate..